# Site Error: 'ansi_x3.110-1983' is not a supported encoding name when reading emails through OpenPop.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am getting this Error while reading Emails from Email server using OpenPop.Net.

> 'ansi_x3.110-1983' is not a supported encoding name:
>
> An unhandled exception has been occurred. The exception description is
> as follows :
>
> System.ArgumentException: 'ansi_x3.110-1983' is not a supported
> encoding name. Parameter name: name at
> System.Globalization.EncodingTable.internalGetCodePageFromName(String
> name) at System.Globalization.EncodingTable.GetCodePageFromName(String
> name) at OpenPop.Mime.Decode.EncodingFinder.FindEncoding(String
> characterSet) at OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart.ParseBodyEncoding(String
> characterSet) at OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart..ctor(Byte[] rawBody,
> MessageHeader headers) at OpenPop.Mime.Message..ctor(Byte[]
> rawMessageContent, Boolean parseBody) at
> OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.GetMessage(Int32 messageNumber) at
> BouncedEmailManager.MainWindow.Init()

Does anyone know how I can solve that error?

### Below is my code what i am writing.

```
pop3Client = New Pop3Client()
 pop3Client.Connect(POPServer, POPPort, False)
 pop3Client.Authenticate(POPUser, POPPassword, AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword)
 AddLogEx("Getting unread messages")

 Dim unreadMessageCount As Integer = pop3Client.GetMessageCount()
 AddLogEx(String.Format("{0} unread messages", unreadMessageCount))

 For iMessage As Integer = 1 To unreadMessageCount
  Dim oPopMessage As OpenPop.Mime.Message = pop3Client.GetMessage(iMessage)
  If Not oPopMessage Is Nothing Then
   Dim msg As Message = SaveMessage(con, oPopMessage, pop3Client, iMessage)
   If Not msg Is Nothing Then
     AddLogEx("Deleting message #" & iMessage)
     pop3Client.DeleteMessage(iMessage)
   End If
  End If
Next
pop3Client.Disconnect()
```

---

I am getting an error on this line:

Dim oPopMessage As OpenPop.Mime.Message = pop3Client.GetMessage(iMessage)

Thanks,

Comment: See following : https://github.com/foens/hpop/blob/master/OpenPop/Mime/MessagePart.cs  Says following in exception : /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">Thrown if the <paramref name="contentTransferEncoding"/> is unsupported</exception>

Comment: the error is telling you that ansi_x3.110-1983 is not supported.  https://github.com/bertjohnson/OpaqueMail/issues/28  This alias is handled with version 2.0.3.

Comment: I am using the latest version, then how am I getting this error. My Version is 2.0.5. Can you tell me how can i fix above issue.

Comment: I have OpenPop.Net.dll version 2.0.5.